# Setting rate of X doesnt affect my whole program

Tags: java, swing, class

Good evening, I am still working on my project (trying to improve myself harder.)

I have a program that converts money to another money type ( like Euro to Dollars ) , I have my menu and I am setting my rates by my own. It sets the rate very well but when I try to convert the money, the setRate doesnt affect it and the result is NaN or Infinity. Here is my whole code.

```
    private JMenuBar menuBar = new JMenuBar(); // Window menu bar
    public Converter(String title) {

        setTitle(title);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setJMenuBar(menuBar); // Add the menu bar to the window
        JMenu fileMenu = new JMenu("File"); // Create File menu
        JMenu elementMenu = new JMenu("Rate Setters"); // Create Elements menu
        JMenuItem subTest = new JMenuItem("Test");
        JMenuItem rateMyMoney = new JMenuItem("Set the Rates.");
        subTest.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){     
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent actionEvent){
                Converter convert = new Converter();

                GridLayout converterGridLayout = new GridLayout(2,2,12,6);
                convert.setLayout(converterGridLayout);
                convert.setVisible(true);
            }
        });

        rateMyMoney.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent actionEvent){

                SetMyRates setRates = new SetMyRates();

                GridLayout setRateGridLayout = new GridLayout(2,2,12,6);
                setRates.setLayout(setRateGridLayout);
                setRates.setVisible(true);
            }
        });


        menuBar.add(fileMenu); // Add the file menu
        menuBar.add(elementMenu); // Add the element menu
        fileMenu.add(subTest);
        elementMenu.add(rateMyMoney);
    }
    public Converter() {

        JPanel dataPanel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(2, 2, 12, 6));
        dataPanel.add(tlLabel);

        dataPanel.add(dollarsLabel);
        dataPanel.add(tlField);
        dataPanel.add(dollarsField);
        JPanel buttonPanel = new JPanel();
        buttonPanel.add(tlButton);
        buttonPanel.add(dollarsButton);
        Container container = this.getContentPane();
        container.add(dataPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        container.add(buttonPanel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        tlButton.addActionListener(new TLConverter());
        dollarsButton.addActionListener(new DollarsConverter());
        buttonPanel.add(setRates);
        pack();

    }
public class SetMyRates extends JFrame{ //extends Converter{
    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public SetMyRates(){

        JPanel dataPanel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(2, 2, 12, 6));
        dataPanel.add(setTLLabel);

        dataPanel.add(setDollarsLabel);
        dataPanel.add(setTLField);
        dataPanel.add(setDollarsField);
        JPanel buttonPanel = new JPanel();
        buttonPanel.add(setTLButton);
        buttonPanel.add(setDollarsButton);
        Container container = this.getContentPane();
        container.add(dataPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        container.add(buttonPanel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        setTLButton.addActionListener(new SetTL());
        setDollarsButton.addActionListener(new SetDollars());
        pack();

    }
};
    private class SetTL implements ActionListener{

        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent  e)
        {
            try
            {
                String input = setTLField.getText();
                System.out.println("text = " + input);
                double tl = Double.parseDouble(input);
                convertMe.setRate(tl);
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Please enter correct Rate.");
            }
        }
    }
    private class SetDollars implements ActionListener{

        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent  e)
        {
            try
            {
                String input = setDollarsField.getText();
                System.out.println("text = " + input);
                double setDolarRate = Double.parseDouble(input);
                convertMe.setRate(setDolarRate);
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Please enter correct Rate.");
            }
        }
    }

    private class TLConverter implements ActionListener
    {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent  e)
        {
            try
            {
                String input = tlField.getText();
                double tl = Double.parseDouble(input);
                convertMe.setTL(tl);

                double dollars = convertMe.getDollars();
                dollarsField.setText(String.format("%.2f", dollars));
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Please enter the amount that will be converted.");
            }
        }
    }


    private class DollarsConverter implements ActionListener
    {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
        {
            String input = dollarsField.getText();
            double dollars = Double.parseDouble(input);
            convertMe.setDollars(dollars);
            double tl = convertMe.getTL();
            tlField.setText(String.format("%.2f", tl));
        }
    }
```

Money.java

```
public class MoneyDetails {

    public double moneyAmount;
    public double myRate;
    public double guaranteeMyRate;



    public double setRate (double myRate){


        System.out.println("myrate = " +myRate);

        this.myRate = myRate;
        System.out.println("this.myrate = " + this.myRate);

        this.guaranteeMyRate = this.myRate;

        System.out.println("garanti = " + guaranteeMyRate);
        return this.myRate;
    }

    public void setTL(double turkishLira) {
System.out.println("setTL = " + turkishLira);
        moneyAmount = turkishLira;
    }

    public void setDollars(double dollars) {
        System.out.println("setDolar = " + dollars);

        moneyAmount = dollars;
    }

    public double getDollars() {

        System.out.println("garanti getdolar = " + guaranteeMyRate);
        return moneyAmount / guaranteeMyRate;
    }

    public double getTL() {

        System.out.println("garanti getTL = " + guaranteeMyRate);

        return moneyAmount * guaranteeMyRate;
    }
}
```

Why doesnt setRate doesnt affect the code when I try to convert it ?

Comment: You really need to include less code. Make it more [sscce](http://sscce.org/). Tell us where exactly is the error you are getting or what goes wrong.

Comment: Everything works fine , The point is , I have 2 submenu on my main menu which is Converter and another is SetRates. Setting rates reads the integer from text field and sets it to setRate on my money.java, For example I set the rate of dollars to 2, and opened my Converter submenu, As an input i wrote 3 so what it should do is 2 / 3 to convert it to Euro, but it doesnt recognize 3 when I open the convert submenu :/

Comment: Then either it is not working fine or something else is wrong... Like I said, does an error occur? Have you debugged the code yet?

Comment: No , It compiles fine. I am not getting any error, First I am setting my rate, then converting money, but here is the result; http://desmond.imageshack.us/Himg221/scaled.php?server=221&filename=screenshot20120502at233oxqh.png&res=landing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It doesn't work because you set conversion rates on your Converter object convertMe field, when clicking on "Rate setters menu".

Then, when you click on test menu, you create another instance of Converter, for which you never set conversion rates.

Fastest and dirty way to solve your problem is to set convertMe field after object creation:

```
        subTest.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent actionEvent){
                Converter convert = new Converter();
                convert.convertMe=Converter.this.convertMe;
                GridLayout converterGridLayout = new GridLayout(2,2,12,6);
                convert.setLayout(converterGridLayout);
                convert.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
```

But I strongly suggest to redesign your UI code. Your Converter class basically build two distinct windows based on the costructor you call. Make a separate class for each of this window, one for the main window and another for the test stuff...

Comment: That one worked very well, Thank you very much. Edit: I'll be doing that with pleasure. Thanks again.